# Mockito's spy functionality fails

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a `public class MClass` that contains a `public static` method `getSysTime()`. In my test I am trying to mock just this one particular method of the class. I basically need that whenever this method of this class is called in the test, it returns a string "FakeTimestamp". The class `MClass` doesn't have any parent class. Following is my code:

```
MClass m = Mockito.spy(new MClass());
Mockito.when(m.getSysTime()).thenReturn("FakeTimestamp");
```

However, I get the following error on test:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.


    at com.scb.edmhdpif.filevalidator.CDCRowCountValidatorTest.CDCRowCountFileDriverTest(CDCRowCountValidatorTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea 15.0.2.
Is there someway I can resolve this error or is there another mock engine that can help in achieving what I need?

Best Regards

Comment: Mockito cannot mock static methods. Use PowerMockito on top of it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: Hmm I thought so initially! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problematic part is that you're trying to spy a `static` method. I.e. it works on non-static instances:

```
public class MClass {

    public String getSysTime() { // this is the tricky one
        return "salala";
    }
}

public class MTest {

    @Test
    public void testSpying() {
        MClass m = Mockito.spy(new MClass());
        Mockito.when(m.getSysTime()).thenReturn("FakeTimestamp");
    }
}
```

In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065515/mockito-bypass-static-method-for-testing) they explain some techniques on dealing with this kind of problem.